# Find maximum sequence of character R and B in Linkedlist

Tags: java

What is the problem in code.

```
  public static int FindMaxseq(Node head){
    Node current=head;
    int count=0,count1=0;
    if(current==null)
        return 0;
    while(current!=null){
        if(current.data=='R'){
            while((current.data=='R')&&(current!=null)){
                current=current.next;
                count++;
            }
        }
     else if(current.data=='B'){
            while((current.data=='B')&&(current!=null)){
                current=current.next;
                count1++;
            }
        }
     else if(current.data=='R'||current.data=='B'){
         current=current.next;
     }
    }
    if(count1>count)
    return count1;
    else
        return count;
}
```

Comment: A good problem description should include more information like exemplary input, expected output, observed output, steps you've undertaken to solve the problem so far, places where you're stuck in your analysis and more - see also [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

One (possibly *the*) problem is that you don't reset `count` or `count1` to `0` for each new sequence of `R`s or `B`s you look at - currently you're getting the total number of `R`s and `B`s.

Don't forget to keep track of the maximum value encountered so far.

The last `else if` doesn't need to test anything - a simple `else` would suffice - if we've reached that part, we already know that the current character is neither an `R` nor a `B`. But if you want to test, you'd have to do `else if(current.data!='R' && current.data!='B')`!

Answer (score 0):

In your loops you check for `null` **after** you access a field. If your last letters are a two `'R'`s or two `'B'`s you'll get a `NullpointerException`; check for null first:

```
while((current!=null) && (current.data=='R')){
```

Also your last if body will never be executed. If

```
(current.data=='R'||current.data=='B')
```

is true, then either `(current.data=='R')` or `(current.data=='B')` must be true which means one of the previous if bodys is executed instead. That also means that you won't visit the next node once you encounter a character different to `'R'` and `'B'`. Furthermore you don't reset the counter when you find a different letter, which means you compute the occurences of `'R'` and `'B'`. Instead of the longest subsequence of either `'R'`s or `'B'`s.